# When using Facebook strategy in passpost.js - user doesn't get returned

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

Am stuck on this and not sure how to proceed.

I am using **passport.js** on **node** and **express** for my authentication and am using the **Facebook Strategy**.

Traditionally, when you are saving a user in a database, you just do the findOne to see if the user exists and return the user and if not, you create a new user and return that user. For me, I am using an API route to do the actual saving so how will I return the user once it is saved using the API instead of being in the actual function?

Code below:

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: config.facebook.appID,
    clientSecret: config.facebook.appSecret,
    callbackURL: config.facebook.callbackURL,
    profileFields: ['id', 'displayName', 'photos', 'emails', 'birthday', 'location', 'bio', 'likes.limit(100)']
},
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done){
    userModel.findOne({'profileID':profile.id}, function(err, user){
        if(user){
            done(null, user);
        } else {
            request({
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/user',
                qs: {id:  profile.id},
                method: 'POST',
                json: {
                    fullname:   profile.displayName,
                    profilePic: profile.photos[0].value || '',
                    email:      profile.emails[0].value || '',
                    birthday:   profile._json.birthday || '',
                    location:   profile._json.location.name || '',
                    about:      profile._json.bio || '',
                    likes:      profile._json.likes || ''
                }
            });

            //What do I put here to return the user like it did earlier using done(null, user);
    }}
    )
}
)
)
```

My route looks like this (which works but I can't make the function above to return it as I am doing it via routing to the API):

```
apiRouter.post('/api/user', function(req, res, next){
    userModel.findOne({'profileID':req.query.id}, function(err, result){
        if(result){
            console.log('User exists already');
        } else {
            var newUser = new userModel({
                profileID   :   req.query.id,
                fullname    :   req.body.displayName,
                profilePic  :   req.body.profilePic || '',
                email       :   req.body.email || '',
                birthday    :   req.body.birthday || '',
                location    :   req.body.location || '',
                about       :   req.body.about || '',
                likes       :   req.body.likes || ''
            });

            newUser.save(function(err){
                console.log('User has been saved');
            })
        }
    })
})
```

By the way, the user being saved directly in the function works but I want my hardcore work to be done by the API side (POST calls).

Your input will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Shayan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't want to make an http request from your internal app to your internal app.  An API (routes, etc) is really designed to be used by other applications.  Since all the logic is in your app, instead of making a public router, you'll want to move your "findOrCreate" code to it's own module/file so you can call it from both places seamlessly.

If your findOrCreate returned a promise, then your passport code can do something like:

```
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done){
  userModel.findOrCreate(profile).then(function(user) {
    done(user);
  });
}
```

And should you need a route later on for browser JS to access, your route code could look like:

```
function(req, res, next){
  userModel.findOrCreate(profile).then(function(user) {
    res.send(user);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment Will! I will go back to the way of not using the API within the app and create them later for external applications should the need arise.

Comment: @ShayanKhan glad to help!